# Why are the initial queries up to minute slow on a 400M record PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following query. The table consists of almost 400 million records and has appropriate indexes.

```
select
      r.id as id,
      r.text as body,
      r.answer as answer
from result r
where
  r.p_id = 12345 and
  r.dirty is null
```

p_id is the variable part of the query which selects the results of that poll. By querying a random p_id, the server takes as long as 60s to fetch results (~300K records). On consecutive calls with the same p_id, it replies almost instantly. I have validated those numbers with `explain analyze`, and they are both reported under `Execution time` (i.e. I'm not accounting for network transmission). It kind of makes sense, even though I don't know the internals of the database.

What I'm trying to improve is the initial time, but I'm not sure where to start. Can the query be further improved? Should I look into the configuration of the server? For the record, the machine seems idle with not a lot IOPS and load.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That are caching effects. The first time, data are read from disk, the other executions already find the data in RAM.

There are several options:

- Have enough RAM in the machine to cache the whole table and the index. Then use [`pg_prewarm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html) to load it into the cache before you begin.
- Get faster storage.
- Use a covering index (which may get large):

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON result (p_id) INCLUDE (id, text, answer) WHERE (dirty IS NULL);
  ```

  See that the index is cached in RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the issue was actually (really) slow storage even though its one of the most expensive choices the cloud provider gives. I should have checked! I'm marking this as the correct answer since you were correct